# custom styling button remove dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

How to style remove file in dropzone. I only need to edit the remove button.

The default code in `Dropzone.js` is like this:

```
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions = {
    dictRemoveFile: "Remove file"
}

if (this.options.addRemoveLinks) {
    file._removeLink = Dropzone.createElement(
        "<a class=\"dz-remove btn btn-default\" href=\"javascript:undefined;\" data-dz-remove>" +
        this.options.dictRemoveFile +
        "</a>"
    );

    file.previewElement.appendChild(file._removeLink);
}
```

I tried to do like this

```
if (this.options.addRemoveLinks) {
    file._removeLink = Dropzone.createElement(
        "<div class=\"custom-btn\"><a class=\"dz-remove btn btn-default\" href=\"javascript:undefined;\" data-dz-remove>" +
        this.options.dictRemoveFile +
        "</a><div>"
    );

    file.previewElement.appendChild(file._removeLink);
}
```

and my code is like this:

```
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
</form>

.custom-btn {
    background: red;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
```

but when I tried to inspect element, it only read

```
<div class="custom-btn">Remove file</div>
```

can somebody help to add a class before tag `a`

Thanks!

Comment: post all the code or a link to your site. No one will help you with what you've provided.

Comment: here sir, i updated it

Comment: `    addRemoveLinks:true,
    RemoveLinkTemplate: "<div class=\"custom-btn\" data-dz-remove><i class=\"icon-cross\"></i></div>",`